# ol3-cesium - is it possible to use an ol3' ImageVector layer as an ImageryProvider for Cesium?

Tags: openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I'm familiar with Cesium but not with OpenLayers. Knowing Cesium's current limitations in drawing vector layers, I'm looking for a way to use OL3 `ImageVector` as an `ImageryProvider` for Cesium. This would allow me easily to display vector data on terrain with the rich styling (dashed strokes etc..) that OL3 offers.

OpenLayers 3 has an `ol.layer.Image` layer that can take an `ol.source.ImageVector` to render an `ol.source.Vector` to an image (canvas) 
[(here's an example)](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/image-vector-layer.html). I would like to take it's output and synchronize it with Cesium.

After looking at some samples and source code, I've found the 
`RasterSynchronizer` and `VectorSynchronizer` which are used respectively to synchronize imagery and vector layers between OL3 and Cesium. Unfortunately, the RasterSynchronizer will only accept a `ol.layer.Tile` and not an `ol.layer.Image`.

**Bottom-line, my question is :** 
Is it possible to synchronize OL3 `ImageVector` as a raster in Cesium, if not how hard should it be to implement it?

**Side note:**
I'm also considering rasterization on geoserver, but would prefer a client side solution

In the image below you can see the difference in the triangle's shape between OL3 (left) to Cesium (right), which I'm trying to eliminate by re-using the `ImageVector`'s output for Cesium's imagery.

[image: OpenLayers 3 vs Cesium]

Comment: Rasterizing vectors prior to handing them off to Cesium means you lose the advantage of WebGL's hardware rasterization.  Have you thought about using Cesium's Primitive Graphics API instead?  For example [PolygonGeometry](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PolygonGeometry.html) and related classes.

Comment: @emackey, Yes I'm aware of that. I've used both Entity and Primitive APIs in Cesium to visualize simple objects. But I have requirements that are beyond Cesium's APIs. I'd like to show vector data with complex dashed lines, repeating fill patterns, better text labels (placement and readability), similar to what OL3 has to offer or SLD. And of course clamp it onto terrain (GroundPrimitives are still not good enough). Mostly my users will see the map in 2D, but for 3D mode, I'd like the data to look the same.